# Cursor gets overflow when scrolling in iphone - safari

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, html, css

I have research and tried a lot to resolve this issue but I couldn't get solution.

[image]

I have textarea like this

CSS

```
.textarea{

    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #bbd7eb;
    color: #5e7891;
    font-family: "Roboto",Arial,"Nimbus Sans L","Helvetica CY",sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    max-width: 560px;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    resize: none;
    width: 100%; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

}
```

HTML

```
<textarea class="textarea" name="" title=""></textarea>
```

In iphone when I enter long para and scroll textarea, cursor goes out of textarea border.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the viewport width? Could it be that it's lower than 570px (5 + 560 + 5) and the textbox exceeds its size (leaving the rightmost part of the textbox hidden from the view)?

Comment: I have used this one - <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

Answer (score 1):

what would you like to achieve?

I did fiddle for you so you can describe with more details?

https://fiddle.jshell.net/mkdizajn/7m54bk5v/show/light/

Where is this property from: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` ? that aint right..

I added overflow: hidden; is that it?

Comment: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` is an iPhone-only thing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling

Comment: Thanks but overflow: hidden will not work for me because I need scroll as well. I found -webkit-overflow-scrolling property from some blog but it also didn't work.

Comment: I have also removed the property and checked but still there is same issue

Comment: I think that what you need is to include some library to scroll the text inside some div or similar.. take a look at this.. https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane

Comment: I have also checked other websites for textarea and over there textarea cursor works fine. in other websites cursor sticks at same position during scroll.

Comment: Even in the fiddle you made it works fine in iphone with the same css. I just removed overflow:hidden css. Than what issue should be there in my page? I can't find out where issue is...

Answer (score 0):

I tried your case on my iPhone 5 (on both Safari and Chrome).

### On Safari

All I could find out is when you scroll touching the blank space on the text area, it is not scrolling the content, instead it is scrolling the entire page.

But when **I tried to scroll by touching the content**, it worked smoothly.

Note: It worked perfectly on Chrome

Comment: Yes it works fine in chrome. Actually I am scrolling content of textarea and not page. When I do that cursor appears on or below textarea border depend on scroling.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution and tested ok on iOS 8.1 at

[cursor out of control in textarea on IOS8 safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376906/cursor-out-of-control-in-textarea-on-ios8-safari)

The cursor of selection is reset and moved to end of the input.