# cursor out of control in textarea on IOS8 safari

Tags: ios8, textarea, mobile-safari

cursor is not in textarea when user input long text or input some enter. This only happens on IOS8. see attachment. [image]

Comment: Gmail still has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find a wordaround to resolve the problem.

```
textarea.addEventListener('scroll', function(evt){
    evt = evt || window.evt;
    evt.target.setSelectionRange(evt.target.textLength - 1, evt.target.textLength - 1);
    setTimeout(function(){
        evt.target.setSelectionRange(evt.target.textLength, evt.target.textLength);
    }, 0);
});
```